# Is there a way to pass an actual instance of a class as a parameter?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

To be more specific, normally when you pass an instance of a class as a parameter for a function, it would be stored as a local variable and then leave scope later, or be returned as a different variable. Is there a way that I could pass the *instance* of the class into the function, and then store it in such a way that modifying the instance passed as a parameter would modify the original version itself?

i.e.

```cs
static void Main()
{
    int j = 0;
    Example(j);
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}

static void Example(linked int param)
{
    param += 100;
}
```

And with the output of course being 100.

By the way here's an example use of this:

You have class, Location, which must be plotted onto a Map. Its constructor asks for coordinates and a Map to be plotted onto. From that point onward, all of its functions called from that specific Location only affect that Map. You can have multiple Locations on the same Map, and multiple Maps.

Comment: That sounds like passing by reference - the ref keyword.

Comment: You aren't passing classes (reference types) in this case you are passing value types, if you want to modify the value, use the `ref` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing classes ([reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)) in this case you are passing [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types), if you want to modify the value, use the [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

```
static void Example(ref int value)
{
    value += 100;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Example(ref j);
```

Comment: Oh, that's so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and it should be pretty easy. Reference types (e.g. classes) by default are a *reference* to an object, so if you have a parameter whose type is a reference type, mutating the state of the object in the function is observed in the calling code.

If, instead, you want to mutate a *value type* (like your `int`), then just preface the type with `ref`:

```
static void Example(ref int param)
{
    param += 100;
}
```

Now the `int` will be *passed by reference*, the method will have a *reference* to the same `int` variable, and your change to the `int` value will be observed by the calling code as well,